# How to build threaded web archive of all email sent to an Exchange distribution group?

Tags: email, exchange, archive, groups

We have an Exchange distribution group for `dev@example.com` that includes all the users on the development team, so mail sent to that address goes to everyone on the team. Is there an easy way to build a web archive of all the email sent to the group, so that we can have hyperlinks to interesting threads of conversation that have occurred in the past? Much like you might get from mailman (like [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/1998-November/000149.html))?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to say

> To: Dude <dude@example.com>
>
> Subject: Re: Please stop reprogramming the coffee machine
>
> Yeah we discussed this last year on dev, see http://mailarchive.example.com/dev/0000345.html

instead of having to attach 37 messages from my inbox to a new mail, assuming I kept them all...

I'm after a **web archive**, not some form of "shared folder" or some other Exchange/Outlook specific thing, because we have folks working on Linux and Mac OS as well as Windows. Most people don't have Outlook and use IMAP. So we have to link to individual messages/threads in a way that work cross platform. If there is another way I'd be happy to hear about it.

I should point out that I don't administer the server myself, have never administered any version of Exchange, and am only reasonably sure that the term "distribution group" is the correct one. I'm basically after an answer I can use to kick-start my request to get this implemented by someone else, who has even less time to spare than I do :)

Comment: Got Sharepoint?

Comment: @joeqwerty. I don't think so... Would that be a solution?

Comment: I believe it would be. One among many options would be to install Sharepoint, set up a Document Library (or other list type), set up a contact in Exchange for the email address of the Sharepoint list, and add the contact to the Distribution Group. The Sharepoint list would then receive a copy of every email sent to the DG. Of course the info I'm giving you here glosses over the technical details, but it gives you a general idea.

Comment: I see thanks. I'd best found out if we've got it then :)

Comment: You can use Sharepoint Foundation 2010 at no cost, but you'll need to pay for the Windows server license to install Sharepoint on.

Comment: @joe Thanks for the tip. Why not post as an answer and you'll get some karma :)

Comment: Consider it done. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One among many options would be to install Sharepoint, set up a Document Library (or other list type), set up a contact in Exchange for the email address of the Sharepoint list, and add the contact to the Distribution Group. The Sharepoint list would then receive a copy of every email sent to the DG. Of course the info I'm giving you here glosses over the technical details, but it gives you a general idea.

You can use Sharepoint Foundation 2010 at no cost, but you'll need to pay for the Windows server license to install Sharepoint on.

Comment: Any solution without sharepoint envolved?